# list index is going out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to make this sample rock paper scissor game and it was working well till I was just outputting the choices.
Now when I added a scoring system as soon as the system picks rock I get the error at the bottom.

```
import random
score=0
options=["rock","paper","scissor"]
while True:
    our_input=input("Please select between rock/paper/scissor or q to quit ").lower()
    if our_input=="q":
        break
    if our_input in options:
        print("you chose "+our_input)
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid input")

    comp_number=random.randint(0,3)
    comp_choice=options[comp_number]
    print("comp chose "+comp_choice)

    if comp_choice=="rock" and our_input=="paper":
        print("You won!")
        score+=1
        print(score)
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It looks like you were expecting [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) to behave like [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation of [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint),

> Return a random integer N such that `a <= N <= b`. Alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`.

So, you can simply do

```
comp_number = random.randint(0, 2)
```

You just have to pick from `0` to `2` only.

Comment: Or if you want to follow the semantics of `range()` (and use half-open ranges) just do `random.randrange(0, 3)` or `random.randrange(3)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
comp_number=random.randint(0,2)
```

Seeing as you only have 3 options, `[rock, paper, scissor]` you only want to have 3 indexes in randomint. `[0, 1, 2]`